# Phpexcel cant download excel file with Firefox

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel library for generate an excel file in my project, is working perfectly when I'm using Chrome but when I use Firefox it does't work, I saw this question , it's something similar to what happens to me, but doesn't solve my problem.

**this is my code:**

```
  public function export_excel($id){

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Builder to do")
        ->setTitle("Export data")
        ->setSubject("Fases")
        ->setCategory("Test data");
    $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Arial');
    $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(10);

    $title_style = array('font'=> array('bold'=> true,'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000'),'size'  => 15,
        'name'  => 'Arial'),'alignment' => array('horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,));
    $headers_styles =array('font'=> array('bold'=> true,'size'  => 11,'name'  => 'Arial'),'fill' => array('type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'a0f4e6')
    ));


  /*---My stuff---*/


    $highColumn =  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:'.'B2');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A3:'.'C4');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A3', 'RESERVAS');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3:'.'C4')->applyFromArray($title_style);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A5:'.$highColumn.'5')->applyFromArray($headers_styles);

    PHPExcel_Shared_Font::setAutoSizeMethod(PHPExcel_Shared_Font::AUTOSIZE_METHOD_EXACT);
    foreach(range('A',$highColumn) as $colID) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($colID)->setAutoSize(true);
    }

    $activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
    $objDrawing->setName('Sample_image')
        ->setDescription('Sample_image')
        ->setpath('outputfiles/img.jpg')
        ->setWidth(35)
        ->setHeight(30)
        ->setCoordinates('A1');
    $objDrawing->setWorksheet($activeSheet);
    $activeSheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(15);
    $activeSheet->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(20);
    $objDrawing->setOffsetX(10)->setOffsetY(10);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Listado');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);



    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('outputfiles/Listado.xlsx');
   // header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
  //  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Listado.xlsx"');
   // header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    echo 'Hello';
   // $objWriter->save('php://output');
    $url = Router::url('/outputfiles/', true).'Listado.xlsx';
    $this->set(array('url' =>$url,'_serialize' => array('url')));
}
```

Comment: what if you remove   the last 4 lines except $objWriter->save('php://output');  ???   i have a code working and you don't need to route anything after that, i think....    it seems like you're trying to save it to disk and the download it from that created file, right??

Comment: with the commented lines works perfectly and I can saw the excel file in my download file using Chrome, but when I use Firefox I dosen't see nothing

Comment: check my answer... I just tested the code to download them in both chrome and firefox and it works just fine..

Comment: `echo 'Hello';` is going to cause problems if you send the file to any browser

Comment: yes, I realized and already remove

Comment: Assuming that you're using some kind of framework; does it allow you to disable its headers if you set your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve the problem, both browser Chrome and Firefox do it the job on the server, but only Chrome export the excel file, so I replace this lines on the Client side

```
  Restangular.all('todos').one('toExprotExcel', $rootScope.client.currentWork.Work.id).customPOST({
                        ids: list,
                        fields: listFields
                    }).then(function (data) {
                        $scope.loadingExcel = false;
                        link.href = data.url;
                       link.download = "Listado.xlsx";
                       link.click();

                    }, function () {
                        $scope.loadingExcel = false;
                    });
                }
                $scope.loadingExcel = false;
            });
```

for this

```
 Restangular.all('todos').one('toExprotExcel', $rootScope.client.currentWork.Work.id).customPOST({
                        ids: list,
                        fields: listFields
                    }).then(function (data) {
                        $scope.loadingExcel = false;

                        window.location.href = data.url;

                    }, function () {
                        $scope.loadingExcel = false;
                    });
                }
                $scope.loadingExcel = false;
            });
```

and this in server

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('outputfiles/Listado.xlsx');
$url = Router::url('/outputfiles/', true).'Listado.xlsx';
$this->set(array('url' =>$url,'_serialize' => array('url')));
```

and works fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

if you JUST want to download (without saving in server) try:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Listado.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

But if you want to save it and then to server and then download it try:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('outputfiles/Listado.xlsx');
header('outputfiles/Listado.xlsx');
```

Comment: still not working, I need to download the excel file into my download file by defect

Comment: i have a code in production just like that and i just installed a new instance of firefox just to check it and it works.. what if you reset the default settings on firefox??  have you tried on other firefox instance??  do you have it on a public accesible server so i could try to download it??

Comment: Actually the proper MIME type for XLSX is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: Use the correct MIME type, as mentioned by @pilsetnieks. If you still see issues, it may be an issue with Firefox. You can find more details about this here: https://github.com/box/spout/issues/197

Comment: I tryd what @pilsetnieks sugest but still not working, and when I add 'header('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');'  dosen't work in FireFox neither in Chrome

Comment: @thirteen Yeah, I didn't mean that it should solve all problems, just that it's one more thing to account for.

Comment: @thirteen why don't you try with another server or another client with firefox??  as i told you before, i have that exact code with PHPExcel 1.8 and it works for chrome and firefox without any problem